# How to use nested foreach loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My array looks like this

```
 productTable:Array(3)
  '[{
      id:1
      name:"Apple"
      today:10
      yearly:21
    },
  {
      id:2
      name:"Banana"
      today:14
      yearly:45
   },
   {
      id:2
      name:"Mangoes"
      today:5
      yearly:95
   },
```

I want to make table like this

```
Period | Apple  | Banana  | Mangoes |
-------+--------+---------+---------+
Yearly |   21   |   45    |   95    |
Today  |   10   |   14    |    5    |
```

and my html code is where id=product title is for Product title & id=product_item is for data like above.

```
         <table>
            <tr id="product_title">
            </tr>
             <tbody>
            <tr id="product_item">
             </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My script file is this; I am getting an error from this. All data are getting undefined.

```
<script>
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productTable')
     .then(response=>response.json())
     .then(data=>{
       $('#product_title').append("<th>Period</th>");
            data.productTable.forEach(function (product) {
            $('#product_title').append('<th>'+product.name +'</th>');
       });
    $.each(['yearly','today'],function (i,period) {
         $('#product_item').append('<td>'+ period +'</td>');
          $.each(data.retailsTable, function(result) {
           $('#product_item').append('<td>'+ result.period +'</td>');
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: @marc_s 
thanks  a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need the separate rows for your periods which you can create with a simple loop and give each row an id from the period value. These rows could also be hard coded into the html if you prefer

Then move the existing period loop inside the loop of the main array so you add the name to heading row and each associated period value to the period rows

For variable property names use `[]` notation

```js
['Yearly', 'Today'].forEach(period => {
  const id = period.toLowerCase();
  const $row = $('<tr>', {id: id}).append($('<th>', {text: period}));
  $('#product_table').append($row)
})

$('#product_title').append("<th>Period</th>");

// loop over each item in array
data.forEach(product => {
  // insert name in heading row
  $('#product_title').append('<th>' + product.name + '</th>');
  // inner loop for each product period value
  ['yearly', 'today'].forEach(period => {
    const $row = $('#' + period);
    $row.append('<td>' + product[period] + '</td>')
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="product_table">
  <tr id="product_title">
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="product_item">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  const data = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Apple",
      today: 10,
      yearly: 21
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Banana",
      today: 14,
      yearly: 45
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Mangoes",
      today: 5,
      yearly: 95
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: If i need to add two more like this type of table  and two different array ? then i think it would be problem ? 
like  i create two table like this then  loop for each product period value will come in only first table ? how can i solve ?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem but code will need to get a bit more specific to isolate each table. Can't use same ids for example